# SELECT CASE statement in TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, case

I have a query with "SELECT CASE" statement that's working fine:

```
SELECT 
(CASE `t`.`is_combined` 
WHEN 0 
THEN `t`.`topic_id` 
ELSE `t`.`is_combined` 
END) AS`group_id`,
    SUM(`ctt`.`tm_download_status`) AS `is_downloaded`, 
    COUNT(`t`.`topic_id`) AS `group_topics_cnt`,
    (SUM(`ctt`.`tm_download_status`) = COUNT(`t`.`topic_id`)) AS `is_downloaded_group` 
    FROM (`catalog_topics` `t` LEFT JOIN `catalog_tracker_torrents` `ctt` ON((`ctt`.`topic_id` = `t`.`topic_id`))) 
    WHERE (`t`.`topic_id` != 0) 
    GROUP BY (`group_id`)
```

So, i want to create a similar trigger to update "cross" table:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `tdg_ins_by_topics` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_topics` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
REPLACE INTO catalog_topics_downloaded_groups(
      SELECT (
              CASE `t`.`is_combined`
              WHEN 0
              THEN `t`.`topic_id`
              ELSE `t`.`is_combined`
              END
     ) AS `group_id` , 
SUM( `ctt`.`tm_download_status` ) AS `is_downloaded` , 
COUNT( `t`.`topic_id` ) AS `group_topics_cnt` , (
SUM( `ctt`.`tm_download_status` ) = COUNT( `t`.`topic_id` ) ) AS `is_downloaded_group`
FROM `catalog_topics` `t`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_tracker_torrents` `ctt` ON `ctt`.`topic_id` = `t`.`topic_id`
WHERE `t`.`topic_id`
IN (
NEW.`topic_id`
)
GROUP BY `group_id`
)
END ;
$$
```

But getting an error message:

> "#"1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 14

It's look like that MySQL doesn't understand difference between `CASE` in `TRIGGER` statement and `CASE` in `SELECT` statement. So, how i can fix this?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: i fixed a grammatical error. About the 14 line - it was first END, i'm forget that phpMyAdmin sends queries after tabbing and string wrapping. Shame on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to "end" your REPLACE statement with `;` like you have to end all statements inside a `TRIGGER` or `PROCEDURE`/`FUNCTION` with a delimeter.

That is why you change the DELIMETER to `$$` .. so you can use `;` to store the mysql default delimeter inside of the trigger code. (and end the create trigger statement with the changed `$$` delimeter)

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `tdg_ins_by_topics` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_topics` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO catalog_topics_downloaded_groups(
          SELECT ( CASE `t`.`is_combined`
                   WHEN 0
                   THEN `t`.`topic_id`
                   ELSE `t`.`is_combined`
                   END
                 ) AS `group_id`, 
                 SUM(`ctt`.`tm_download_status`) AS `is_downloaded`, 
                 COUNT( `t`.`topic_id` ) AS `group_topics_cnt` , 
                 (
                 SUM( `ctt`.`tm_download_status` ) = COUNT( `t`.`topic_id` ) ) AS `is_downloaded_group`
          FROM `catalog_topics` `t`
          LEFT JOIN `catalog_tracker_torrents` `ctt` ON `ctt`.`topic_id` = `t`.`topic_id`
          WHERE `t`.`topic_id` IN ( NEW.`topic_id` )
          GROUP BY `group_id`
    );
END;
$$
DELIMETER ;
```